# How do I parse through a text file in python and print into another text file or json file?

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file which is basically a list like:

```
CustomId: 123412412
Name: blah blah
```

I would like to parse through this text file line by line and only print lines that I need that I will specify eventually. Right now I can go parse through the file and print it. However I am having trouble trying to think of logic that will parse through and print only required lines from the list.

Comment: In terms of conditions I would like the lines to meet. If the line is included I would like the line to show up with its label and then the specification. So I would want CustomId: 123345

Comment: This question is very vague. Please give a specific example input file and a clear specification of which lines you want to print. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You also should explain more about your efforts to solve this problem, preferably including code.

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer. Probably is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find(search, file_input_path, file_output_path):
  output = open(file_output,"a")
  f = open(file_input_path,'r')
  lines = f.readlines()
  for l in lines:
     if(l == search):
       output.write(s[1]))
  output.close()
  f.close()
```

Example of usage:

```
find("Name: blah blah", "input.txt", "output.txt")
```

Will produce an output in the other file like this:

```
Name: blah blah
```

If you want to find more lines just call the function inside a loop.

Comment: This works! I put the function inside the loop and I can do what I needed to. The logic would stay the same whether it is a text file or a json file too

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what kind of conditions you want the lines in your file to meet, you can iterate over individual lines with the following:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # conditional statements here
            # write to output file if condition is met
```

To write to the output file you can use the following:

```
with open(output_file, 'a') as out:
    out.write( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

With the information that you have provided, it seems as if this might work -

```
file = open('your-file', 'r')
outputFile = open('outputFile.txt', 'w')
for line in file:
    if #put condition here ( Eg : if 'hello' in line: ):
        outputFile.write(line)
file.close()
outputFile.close()
```

You can put your condition for the required lines in the `if` clause in the for loop.

Hope it solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
l=[]
with open("data.txt") as finp, open("output.txt","w") as fout:
         cid,name=None,None
         for line in finp:
             key,sepa,value=line.partition(":")
             if "CustomId" in key:
                 cid=value.strip()
             elif "Name" in key:
                 name=value.strip()
                 if cid and name: # neither is None
                     l.append((cid,name))
                     fout.write( f"ID:{cid}, Name:{name}\n" )
                 cid,name=None,None # it helps detecting wrong line pairing
```

This is an example to store the data into a list and a file. You may leave the list handling, and you can add filtering, e.g.:

```
if "CustomId" in key and "1234567"==key.strip():
           ...
```